# How can I use the RPi GPIO to make a headphone sensing audio jack?

Tags: gpio, audio, sensor, breadboard

I am working on a project that involves a raspberry pi acting as an internet radio client which the public can access by plugging their own headphones into a 3.5mm (1/8”) jack. They will have access to volume control and nothing else. 
The project’s constrains are:

- the plug has to be robust, and panel-mountable
- the sound quality must be good
- the raspberry pi must know when someone has plugged in.

I am using a usb soundcard connected to a headphone amp to give me volume control, and higher quality sound. for the robust plug and sensing capability, the headphone out is connected to a breadboard which connects to a high quality 3 conductor 4 pin barrel jack and contains a circuit that interfaces with the RPi’s GPIO.

The jack contains a switch which is normally closed, and is opened when a plug is in the jack.
I’ve attached a link to the circuit on the breadboard.

The circuit behaves properly when the headphone amp is not turned on, or when the sound source is ungrounded, such as a smart-phone, but when the soundcard out is used, or the headphone amp is on, the GPIO digital pin remains high.

I think it is an issue with the relative grounds of the RPi and the headphone amp. I found the circuit I'm using [here](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4607). I’m not very savvy with electronics, so I'm not sure what changes to make to get the proper behaviour, but it feels like I'm so close. Is there a simple solution?

Here's the circuit I'm using:

R1=100k, R2=50k, R3=10k, C1=0.1uF

[fritzing circuit schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8NFG.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround, but would still love to hear an explanation for the behavour exhibited above..

After a bit of experimenting, I found that eliminating R3 got the voltages within bounds of the GPIO threshold states. When the switch was open, V at GPIO was 2.85, when closed, V was 0. The problem was that every time I connected my headphones, I would hear the loud pop from the high dc offset which is somehow created by the interaction of the headphone amp and gpio pins. Not good for ears or headphones; I don't know what it might do to the life-expectancy of the Pi.

I've decided to keep R3, but bypass the headphone amp, and use a 1k log pot to give volume control. Sound quality is still quite high, and there are no noises when connecting or disconnecting.

I would still love to hear any solutions or explanations for the behaviour exhibited by the circuit with the headphone amp, but for anyone else who wants to have a headphone sensing jack for their Raspberry Pi, here's an updated diagram.
The kind of jack I'm using is 3 conductor 4 contact, [like this one.](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/SJ1-3514N/CP1-3514N-ND/738685)
and I'm using a 1k dual gang log pot, such as [this one](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/KKA1021S28/KKA1021S28-ND/738784).

Here is my final circuit, same values as before, but with the added 1k pot. The switches just represent the behaviour of the headphone jack.[image]